# How to make fixed header in table with help of div?

Tags: css, html-table, position

HTML:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><div style="width:36px"><textarea class="cell"></textarea></div></th>
    <th><div style="width:36px"><textarea class="cell"></textarea></div></th>
</tr>
<div class="header">
    <tr>
        <th><div style="width:36px"><textarea class="cell">Name 1</textarea></div></th>
        <th><div style="width:36px"><textarea class="cell">Name 2</textarea></div></th>
    </tr>
</div>
</thead>
```

CSS:

```
div.header {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('div.header').css({
        'top': $(this).scrollTop()
    });
});
```

I want to leave in place first fake header row to apply column widths to the table and move other rows when scrolling, but they don't move. What I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the div you can give you tbody a fixed height and overflow:auto. This will allow the body of the table to scroll

Comment: Indeed, though you can use the native `<thead>` with `<tbody>` elements and just make the `<thead>` fixed.

Comment: @Brad: no, fixed isn't acceptable, I need to scroll header horizontally

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/EnmPH/)**

Is that solution possible?

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><div style="width:36px"><textarea class="cell"></textarea></div></th>
    <th><div style="width:36px"><textarea class="cell"></textarea></div></th>
</tr>
<div class="header">
    <tr>
        <th><div class="horizontal"><textarea class="cell">Name 1</textarea></div></th>
        <th><div class="horizontal"><textarea class="cell">Name 2</textarea></div></th>
    </tr>
</div>
</thead>
```

CSS

```
.horizontal {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:20px;
width:150px;
}
.header{
height:35px;
width:165px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: No, widths are all breaking and header is not fixed